# Losing data calling several methods in php - OOP

Tags: php, oop, instantiation

Perhaps it is a very simple issue, but I'm missing something in OOP fundamentals. Suppose I have to php file, say file1 and file2. file1 implements a class from the class Class, and in some of the method of the latter, say MethodA. In MethodA, I instantiate a class say $object from the class Object (which comes from another file3), and I call a method, say MethodB that takes as an argument the instantiation $object, and processes to set the value of one attribute of the instantiation $object. So, the scheme is the following :

```
class Class{

    public function MethodB($object){

        $param
        ...
        $object->setValue($param);
        ...

    }

    public function MethodA(){

        $object = new Object;
        ...
        $this->MethodB($object);
        ...
        $object->getValue();
    }

}
```

Now the problem is that I am not able to get back the value of `$object->getValue($param)`, and the question is why?

Comment: What is `$param` in `MethodB()`? What arguments does `MethodA` take?

Comment: $param is just a toggle parameter taking 0 or 1 as value. Btw, Method takes no argument, in fact when calling the class Class, a $_GET method take a specfic value that calls $this->MethodA()

Comment: The code still doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but no information is "lost" like you're saying: http://codepad.org/HT4bWZd5

Comment: @NullUserException, sorry I mistook in my code, in fact the getValue() method takes no parameter : the class Object, has an attribute, say protected $attribute, the setValue($param) sets the value of $object->attribute to $param, and then the getValue() fetchs the value of $object->attribute

Comment: Still works: http://codepad.org/fQ3YcrRc

Comment: Would you mind giving us a **reproducible** piece of code? We can't, and won't, guess the problem with your semi-mystery code.

Comment: @NullUserException, you got it. It is indeed this is my exact scheme and it doesn't seem to work on my side. In fact, I am trying to debug and adding echo($object->getValue()); exit; but I can't display the result (in my chrome console). Could you advise me a trick to detect this value I am missing

Comment: @user1611830 Do `var_dump($object->getValue());`, echo won't print anything if the value is `null` for example (most likely the case here).

Comment: Listen to @MadaraUchiha. Often times, just *creating* that reproducible piece of code sheds light on the problem.

Comment: I'll guess the problem is within `Object` itself. It's the only factor we do not see here.

Comment: In fact, the code is very complicated, I just made it really more simple. But I think now I can debugg it on my own, I just wanted to ensure myself I wasn't missing something in OOP. Thanks a lot both !

Comment: @user1611830: You don't understand my point. Creating a reproducible testcase doesn't mean dump your whole code at us. It means, create the smallest, simplest possible snippets which shows the problem clearly.